# Finding the variable of a coordinate point on a circle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, circles

This might be a very simple question but I am having trouble figuring it out, so if anyone can explain: 
A circle is marked with three points `A(-3,2)`,`B(9,10)` and `C(x,4)`. All three points lie on the circle.
Given that `AC` is a diameter of the circle how would you find the value of the variable `x`?

Comment: hint : angle inside semi circle is always a **right** angle, see http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~dwiggins/pict46.GIF

Comment: Different hint: If $AB$ is a diameter of the circle, then what is the radius and the center of the circle? What does that imply about $x$?

Comment: Oh, I'm really sorry I meant to type that AC is the diameter. Should have double checked the question before posting.

Comment: Good catch. But the same hint applies except with $AC$.

Answer (score 2):

If AC is a diameter of the circle, then $\angle B = \dfrac {π}{2}$.

Therefore, $m_{AB} . m_{BC} = –1$. That is, $\dfrac {10 - 2}{9 - -3} . \dfrac {10 - 4}{9 - x} = -1$.

$x = ... = 13$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\overline{AC}$ is a diameter of the circle, its midpoint $M(\frac{x-3}{2},3)$ is the center. From the definition of the circle, it follows that $|BM|^2=|CM|^2$ i.e.

$$\hspace{12mm}\left(9-\frac{x-3}{2}\right)^2+(10-3)^2=\left(x-\frac{x-3}{2}\right)^2+(4 -3)^2$$
\begin{align}
\implies \left(9-\frac{x-3}{2}\right)^2-\left(x-\frac{x-3}{2}\right)^2
&=12(9-x)\\&=(4 -3)^2-(10-3)^2\\&=-6(8)\implies \fbox{$x=13$}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

If $AC$ is a diameter then $\widehat{ABC}=\frac{\pi}{2}$, hence $BC$ is orthogonal to $AB$ and we can find the abscissa of $C$ by intersecting the $y=4$ line with the perpendicular to $AB$ through $B$, whose equation is $y=-\frac{3}{2}x+\frac{47}{2}$. Setting $4=-\frac{3}{2}x+\frac{47}{2}$ gives $x=13$.